# how to add Element UI to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, element-ui

I am trying to add Element UI into my Vue3 Project:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

App.use(ElementUI)
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

So I am following this documentation https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart but it gives me this error: types.js?a742:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

I dont know what I am doing wrong in this regard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`element-plus`](https://element-plus.org/en-US/) which is compatible with vue 3:

Installation :

```
  npm install element-plus --save
```

Usage :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(ElementPlus)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nuxt 3, you create a plugin

Install:

```
npm install element-plus --save
```

Plugin: plugins/elementui.js

```
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ElementPlus)
})
```

Add the plugin to nuxt.config.ts

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/elementui.js', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

Using (without imports) pages/index.vue:

```
<el-table :data="list">
  <el-table-column prop="MY_PROP" label="PROP" />
</el-table>
```